# Dealing with pointers and vectors in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, tree

I'm constructing a tree with `node` classes that have two pointers to subnodes. While constructing the tree, I use vectors of nodes for manipulation and I end up pointing them to eachother. I often need to pop them off of the vector to maintain the logic of the linking process. Unfortunately, if I point to a node and pop it off the vector, the object is destroyed (to my understanding). Any ideas on how to keep my pointers pointing to the right place, or better systems?

Edit --
If it helps, here are some specifics:

I have an array of vectors of nodes: `Vector<node> nVec[3]`

for each level of parsing I need to do for my program, it will fill these 3 vectors with nodes. Then, based on other parse data, I will systematically link the nodes. To do this, I fill the vector, and at a certain point I need to link to the `nVec[3].back()` from some node in `nVec[2]` and pop it off so that, if I want to do it again, I won't be linking to the same element.

Comment: That's too vague. Post your code

Comment: By your very definition, if you pop and throw out a node from a fundamental value vector, there is no more "right place" to point to. Ensure nothing points to the node being popped, or use `std::shared_ptr<>` if your design is too hardened to turn back now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you store in them in the `std::vector`. If you have a `std::vector<node>`, then yes, the `node` objects stored in the vector will be destroyed when you remove them from it.

However, if you have a vector of pointers (`std::vector<node*>`) and dynamically allocate your nodes before pushing them in (`nodes.push_back(new node();)`) they will stick around until you explicitly `delete` them. However, you would have to remember to `delete` these nodes later on. To safely use dynamic allocation, use a vector of smart pointers, such as `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should store pointers to objects already in your `vector`:

```
vector<Node> nodes;
nodes.push_back(Node(foo));
```

is **NOT** good.

```
vector<Node*> nodes;
nodes.push_back(new Node(foo));
```

is good because now node is allocated onto the heap and won't get destroyed when removed from the collection.

I suggest you to use a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) (`unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`) to manage resource allocation and deallocation since at this point you could end up forgetting how many references to a single object you have.

Comment: *Don't* use `auto_ptr<>`, which is the white zinfandel of smart pointers, trying so hard to do it all and falling just short *at everything it tries*. There's a reason it was deprecated in C++11. Use either `std::unique_ptr<>` or `std::shared_ptr<>`